# Eclipse Kepler File Search keep crashing

Tags: java, eclipse

Hi I'm Using Eclipse Kepler, and every time I search a string via file search it keeps crashing. I have refresh the project and restart my computer, deleted savedIndexNames file but still no luck. It just starting to not respond, Could some one please help? Because this is so annoying and frustrating...

Comment: increase heap for eclipse. Search in stackoverflow to know how to increase head size for eclipse.

Comment: Check the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory for any messages.